# Load file file with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to load a file, contains vars' statements.

For example, `VLANS.conf` will contain `$VLANS = "VLAN1500", "VLAN877"`

How do I load it into powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file content and use the Invoke-Expression cmdlet to evaluate each line as an expression:

```
PS > Get-Content .\VLANS.conf | Foreach-Object {Invoke-Expression $_}
PS >$VLANS
VLAN1500
VLAN877
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative is to have a VLANS.ps1 or VLANS.conf.ps1 or something and "dot source the file"?

```
. .\VLANS.ps1
```

You will have the advantage of having here-strings, script blocks ( and of course anything you can have in a powershell script)